# How can I render interactive plots into static html to be sent and rendered in an email

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, plotly, rnotebook

When I use interactive charts from [plotly](https://plot.ly/r/) or tables from [datatables](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) and I use [rmarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) `rmarkdown:::render` to html I can get interactive charts in a web browser.

When I try to send this html file as an email the interactive graphs are purely not displayed.

I'd like to be able to send a static (I mean non interactive html) so the file can be rendered in the email.

Is it possible ?

Example:

````
---                                                                                                     
title: "Sample Document"                                                                                
output:                                                                                                 
  html_document:                                                                                        
    toc: true                                                                                           
    theme: united                                                                                       
---                                                                                                     

```{r Code Chunk}                                                                                       
d <- diamonds[sample(1:nrow(diamonds), size = 2000),]                                                   
plot_ly(d, x = ~carat, y = ~price, color = ~carat, size = ~carat, text = ~paste("Clarity: ", clarity))  
```                                                                                                     

```{r run code, echo=FALSE, eval=FALSE}                                                                 
library(rmarkdown)                                                                                      
library(plotly)                                                                                         
rmarkdown:::render('./dyn_2_statix_html.Rmd')
```
````

Which would give the following `html` page rendered:
[image]

Comment: #1 The post would be more valuable if it had a minimal & executable example of what you got. #2 What's `rdatatable`? #3 Can't you export your plotly graph to an image using `plotly::export()`, for example? This could be inline embedded into your html.

Comment: @lukeA you may be right about `plotly::export`, though I was hoping to be able to run something on the html file produced instead of writing if elses in the document, and that's only for plotly... not DT or other things i could use

Comment: I maybe wrong but I don't think there's a way around if-elsing or making two docs. In the email doc, Or you send the html as an attachment so that the recipients can open it in their browsers.